# How to select text that have no class or id using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select text from html below, I want to select only this text

**Adobe Illustrator, Adobe Photoshop**

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
 <h4 class="dl-title">Professional Skills</h4>
 <div class="divider"></div>
Adobe Illustrator, Adobe Photoshop
```

here is my code

```
$('.col-xs-12:not(.dl-title)').eq(15).text().trim()
```

I use eq(15) because in the website that I going to get data from has alot of **.col-xs-12**.

Please help me! Thanks in advance

Comment: `$('.col-xs-12:eq(15) .divider')[0].nextSibling.textContent`

Comment: @ArunPJohny, This should be an answer. Not sure why didn't you put it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Use This:

```
$('.col-xs-12').children().remove().end().text().trim()
```

When you need to add any class or .eq(15) then add

Comment: Thank you so much everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$.parseHTML()` , `.html()` , `Array.prototype.pop()` , `.textContent`

```
var text = $.parseHTML($(".col-xs-12").eq(15).html()).pop().textContent;
```

```js
var text = $.parseHTML($(".col-xs-12").html()).pop().textContent;
console.log(text)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <h4 class="dl-title">Professional Skills</h4>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  Adobe Illustrator, Adobe Photoshop
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $(".col-xs-12")
        .clone()    //clone the element
        .children() //select all the children
        .remove()   //remove all the children
        .end()  //again go back to selected element
        .text();
```